# Can I ask that a closed mathSE query not be deleted

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request

A mathSE query posted by someone received interesting info in an answer by someone else.  I have bookmarked this query.  Since it has been closed, I have also downloaded the (full) html page, just to be safe, in case the query is deleted.

For the next time that such a situation occurs, I am wondering whether such a precaution is needed.  Can I prevent a query that has been closed from being deleted?  Assuming not, is it possible to request that if the query is *going to be* deleted, that before it is deleted, I receive notification, either by email or a mathSE message, so that I can *then* download the query, *just before* it is deleted.

Finally, assuming that none of the above is feasible, and assuming that I keep a specific record of the query's title and the url that *was* assigned to it, what precisely does it mean for a query to be *deleted*?  Does that mean that it's *immediately* gone for good?  Can I *recover* a deleted query just for the purposes of downloading it to my hard drive?  Is there a *transition* period, after the query is *deleted* where it is not yet *gone for good*?

Although I have included the *feature-request* tag, the primary intent of this query is to better understand the intricacies of mathSE's delete-query process.  If a feature can be added to address my concern, great; but at this point all I'm asking for is to understand the process.

---

**Addendum-1**
Responding to the comments so far.

The question that I *safeguarded* is [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4087426/proof-for-a-theorem-about-relations-beween-convergents-in-continued-fractions).  In fact, the reason that I safeguarded this problem was because of the information in Will Jagy's answer + his subsequent comments.

I have already saved the corresponding webpage for this specific question to my hard drive, so this particular question is not an issue.

Also, I wasn't intending to use mathMetaSE in general for such requests.  This meta question is a *one time only* request for general information, not pertaining to any specific question, currently deleted or closed.

In fact, I think one of amWhy's comments has completely resolved the issue, given that I will soon be at a 10k+ rep.  I have no interest in undeleting any already deleted query, or requesting such a deletion.  My only concern is whether I can still privately access such a question simply to re-examine the information on it.

According to amWhy's comment, all I have to do, once I reach 10+k rep is to review the help articles or perhaps meta queries for documentation on how to (*privately*) examine a *deleted* question.

Comment: Please post a link to the question (the word typically used on this site, whereas "query" often refers to a search.)  Are you asking in general, if you can ask that a question not be deleted, or did you have a particular concern about a specific question, and if so, please link it.

Comment: You can post such a question about a specific question in CURED, provided you provide an argument why it should not be deleted.  You can request reopening or undeletion of a post on the dedicated thread for doing so which is on meta.  But I don't think it is well advised to post to meta each and every time a post is closed, to request that it not be deleted.

Comment: In short, you really need to include more context in your post here.

Comment: To your third "paragraph", the deletion of a question doesn't make it disappear entirely, it is still accessible to mods and high rep users, and I believe when you cap 10,000 rep, you will be able to see deleted answers when clicking on a link to such a question, if you've bookmarked them at any point.  It then becomes just a matter of keeping a link to the question, either by following, or bookmarking it.  Good luck!  You are almost there (10K!)

Comment: @amWhy I responded to your comments with an Addendum.

Comment: Thanks for the update!  But there is no way to search through deleted question.  You need to preserve a link to questions you might want to revisit, via bookmarking it.

Comment: @amWhy What about a MathSE question that I personally answered that was subsequently deleted (i.e. a few months ago)?  I failed to bookmark the question.  I've noticed in my user interface that I can access *recently deleted answers*.  Unsure how that applies to something deleted several months ago.

Comment: That could likely be handled through a question to moderators, or perhaps by adjusting your question to address such scenarios.  They have full access, and the more details you have to give them about when, or topic, etc., the easier it will me, certainly once you reach 10K.

Comment: ^^^I meant adjusting your question above to better understand what would happen if it's no longer recently deleted.

Comment: @amWhy good point, assuming that you mean my Meta Question.  However, there is only one deleted answer that I specifically care about, so it's not that big a deal.  Your comments resolved any questions that I had re the intent of this Meta Query.  I won't be making a *future* habit of failing to bookmark, if the mathSE question + answers look interesting.  My last comment/question was just an insignificant tangential question.

Comment: In addition to what has been said above, it is (kind of) possible to search deleted posts using the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/).  I have not used the SEDE much (at all), and I suspect that there is a difficult learning curve to tackle, but it is yet another tool which exists.

Comment: No-one has mentioned "comments" yet: comments are different. Once an individual comment is deleted then it is gone forever and we cannot see them, regardless of rep. score (but maybe mods can @Xander?). So as some of the material you care about is contained in comments, then having a backup isn't such a bad idea. Maybe a better option though would be to convince Will Jay to add his comments to the answer?

Comment: (This is just for comments deleted individually, e.g. if Will Jay deleted his comments because he didn't like them any more. If the question was deleted and then undeleted then the comments would still be there.)

Comment: I congratulate you in advance on reaching the 10k milestone.

Comment: @hardmath Thanks, appreciate it.

Comment: Yes, mods see an icon showing how many comments have been directly deleted, and by clicking can then see deleted comments. @user1729